# Commerce: How can I check that a user has bought a product?

Tags: current-user, products

I have a digital product, with a landing page, and I want to know if the connected user has already bought the product so I can give him access to the content.

Answer (score 1):

There is a direct way to find this out.

Here's an example.  Note the `id` you supply must be the specific purchasableId, not the product id (so the `defaultVariant.id` or `variant.id`).

```
{# Has the customer explicitly bought the XXX product? Returns 0 (==false) or >= 1 (==true) #}

{% set purchasedXXX = craft.orders()
    .user(currentUser)
    .hasPurchasables(10637)
    .isCompleted()
    .count()
%}
```

You can then use that as just

```
{% if purchasedXXX %}
 ...
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jeremy's answer is right, but for people using the Digital Products plugin, this command might be a better fit:

```
{# Has the customer explicitly bought the XXX product? Returns 0 (==false) or >= 1 (==true) #}
{% set licenses = craft.digitalProducts
    .licenses
    .owner(currentUser)
    .product(productID)
    .count()
%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
  {% set found = false %}
  {% set orders = craft.orders()
    .customer(craft.commerce.customer)
    .all() %}
  {% for order in orders %}
    // here you could / should also check if the order was paid
    {% for lineItem in order.lineItems %}
      {% if lineItem.purchasableId == yourProductId %}
        {% set found = true %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% if found %}
      // user has bought product before 
  {% endif %}
```

There might be more efficient query-wise.

Comment: There's a much more direct way available with recent Commerce versions, see my answer.